# ¿Cómo saber si mi arreglo contiene duplicados y como obtenerlos?

Tags: c#

Me gustaría comprender como puedo saber si mi arreglo tiene valores repetidos dentro de sus indices y de ser así como poder obtenerlos. quiero hacer esto con la finalidad de poder sacar todos los números con repetición, cada numero es un id de la BD y por ende cada registro con ese numero debería pertenecer a una tabla diferente.

**Creación del Arreglo:**

```
String[] valores = idEmpresa.Split('|');
```

**Llenado del arreglo:**

```
for (int x = 0; x < valores.Length; x++)
{
    valores[x] = Convert.ToString(idEmpresa[x]);
}
```

**Comparación actual:**

```
bool pares = valores.Distinct().Count() == valores.Length;
```

Nota: la comparación actual solo me da un verdadero o un falso y aunque es correcto, yo quisiera saber en que indice, cuales y cuantos valores son los repetidos.

Answer (score 5):

En vez de usar [`Distinct()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx), puedes usar [`GroupBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx) y luego filtrar por los "grupos" que contienen más de un elemento, o sea, que contienen duplicados.

Aquí te dejo un pequeña demostración usando [LINQ](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String[] valores = new[] {"abc", "xxx", "abc", "abc", "jaja", "hola", "jaja"};

    foreach(var grouping in valores.GroupBy(t => t).Where(t => t.Count() != 1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("'{0}' está repetido {1} veces.", grouping.Key, grouping.Count()));
    }
}
```

Salida:

> 'abc' está repetido 3 veces.
>   'jaja' está repetido 2 veces.

<kbd>[**Demostación**](http://rextester.com/PRY15523)</kbd>

Comment: Porque pusiste el 0 y el 1 en la impresion de consola

Comment: El `{0}` y `{1}` sone notaciones especiales que `string.Format` entiende. En este caso, `string.Format` los reemplaza con los valores de `grouping.Key` y `grouping.Count()` respectivamente. Puedes leer mas en cuanto a eso leyendo la documentación para `string.Format`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que entiendo necesitas obtener los valores, cantidad de repeticiones y en que índices se encuentran.

A partir de la solución de @sstan:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String[] valores = new[] {"abc", "xxx", "abc", "abc", "jaja", "hola", "jaja"};
        //String[] valores = idEmpresa.Split('|');

        foreach(var registro in 
                valores.Select((v, i) => new { Indice = i, Valor = v}) // Obtener indice y valor
                .GroupBy(x => x.Valor) // Agrupar por el valor
                //.Where(x => x.ToList().Count() > 1) // En caso necesitas obtener cant. repetidas mayor a 1
                .Select(x => new{ 
                        Valor = x.Key, // key de la agrupación (valor)
                        Cantidad = x.Count(), // Cantidad de duplicidad
                        Indices = string.Join(", ", x.Select(i => i.Indice.ToString()).ToArray()) // Concatenar los indices
                                }))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Valor: '{0}'\tCant. Repetidas: {1}\tIndices: {2}", registro.Valor, registro.Cantidad, registro.Indices));
        }
    }
```

Completo agregando los indices donde se repite.

> Valor: 'abc'  Cant. Repetidas: 3  Indices: 0, 2, 3
>
> Valor: 'xxx'   Cant. Repetidas: 1  Indices: 1
>
> Valor: 'jaja'  Cant. Repetidas: 2  Indices: 4, 6
>
> Valor: 'hola'  Cant. Repetidas: 1  Indices: 5

Answer (score 0):

Puedes resolver de la siguiente manera, 
digamos que queremos trabajar sobre el siguiente `array`

```
{7, 3, 4, 1, 0, 2, 2, 7, 1, 6}
```

necesitamos un array del mismo tamano inicializado todo en cero

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

cada posición representa cada numero del `array` 
y vamos contando las ocurrencias segun los valores de `array` de la siguiente manera:
`counter[array[i]-1]++;`

```
 using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;

        public class Program
        {
          public static void Main()
          {
            int[] array = new int[10]{7, 3, 4, 1, 0, 2, 2, 7, 1, 6};
            int[] counter = new int[10]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

         for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++){
            counter[array[i]-1]++;
        }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Si usas una lista por ejemplo

```
 List<string> lista = new List<string>
```

puedes luego copiar el arreglo a esa lista y luego con

```
lista.Distinct()
```

puedes eliminar los duplicados , te puede servir para tener un arrary solo con los elementos unicos.